# Drupal - use l or url function for mailto links

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hyperlink

Does anyone know how to use the l() or url() function to create mailto links?

I am running drupal 6.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the absolute option:

```
l('Mail me', 'mailto:jim@hotmail.com', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

will generate

```
<a href="mailto:jim@hotmail.com">Mail Me</a>
```

Comment: You may want to add quotes around 'absolute'. Just for people out there learning PHP...

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to use the [t() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) with strings. Code should be then:

```
l(t('Mail me'), 'mailto:jim@hotmail.com', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Drupal 9+ solution

Drupal core has this code in `Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\MailToFormatter`:

```php
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => $item->value,
        '#url' => Url::fromUri('mailto:' . $item->value),
      ];
```

So you can create a render array like so:

```php
[
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => $email,
  '#url' => Url::fromUri('mailto:' . $email),
];
```

Or like this:

```php
Link::fromTextAndUrl($email, Url::fromUri('mailto:' . $email))->toRenderable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferably none:

l() is useful for the output of internal links:

> it handles aliased paths and adds an 'active' class attribute to links that point to the current page (for theming)"
>   [see reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

You need none of the above. Same goes for url(). You CAN use them, but why not keeping it simple and just use the HTML anchor tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9 I found no other solution than:

```
$this->t('<a href="@link">This is a mail link</a>', ['@link' => 'mailto:mail@example.com']);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.